# Typescript doesn't produce error with mishandling of types

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Just started experimenting with typescript and I don't understand why the below behavior doesn't cause an error.

```
const fun = (n1: number, n2: number) => {
     console.log(n1 + n2);
};

const num1 = 5;
let num2;
num2 = "something";

const res = fun(num1, num2);
```

Well I understand that if I declare num2 as this:

```
let num2: number;
```

It would produce error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

**But since I have declared in the fun function that I am expecting an input of type *number* shouldn't it give an error just by passing a string?**

Note: I also see with usage of

```
const fun = (n1: number, n2: number) => {
  console.log(n1 + n2);
};

const num1 = 5; 
const num2 = "something";

const res = fun(num1, num2);
```

Error produced is as expected: error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Comment: Do you have the `noImplicitAny` flag turned on? Your first example doesn't compile for me (with all strict flags enabled at least). See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzDAvDAFGAjALhmBAWwCMBTAJwBp8AmPAkigSlQD4YBvAWACgZ-+oSCAA2pAHQiQAc0xYYAalpMA3LwC+anryHR8ReWgCsWsbAY0tF1DABEEEIVJQAFgEsw021p3g95UggbRDBMA2oLVSA)

Comment: I have never used those flags you are using. Is there some documentation I can read on?

Comment: Sure https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

Comment: Yes if I use the flag you specified during compiling it creates the error. My question though is why doesn't the function produce an error since I have specified there that input should be number.

Comment: Just a side note, these are not generic types, genric would be something like `n1: T`.

I have ran your first example in the Typescript Playground and it infact DOES produce the error you are expected. There must be something up with your configuration. You can check your example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzDAvDAFGAjALhmBAWwCMBTAJwBp8AmPAkigSlQD4YBvAKBl99EggANqQB0QkAHNMWGAGpaTANxcAviq4Do+IrLQBWFSNgMaK06hgAiCCEKkoACwCWYSVY1bY5UhEuIwTF1qU2UgA) in the typescript playground

Comment: @Emobe Yes removed the wrong tag. Thanks for the answer indeed in the TS playground it produces expected result. In my configuration only a warning for type any is produced. Thank you.